# Torch + nn: Dies with "illegal instruction" on some computers

Tags: machine-learning, lua, installation, torch

I'm hoping to do undergraduate research with Torch and deep neural networks.  However, I'm having problems getting Torch to even install properly on my advisor's server.

The behavior I'm seeing is that when I run the code at the end of this post on my advisor's server, the program makes it to the `criterion:forward(mlp:forward(input), output)` line and dies with `Illegal Instruction`.   However, on my local install, the program runs to completion and prints results.

As such, I believe there is a problem with the install on my advisor's machine.  My questions are, then: 1) can someone confirm if this is a known/common problem, and 2) how do I need to fix this?

```
-- Trains NN to recognize the function:
-- f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 * x_2 > 0).

-- We're going to use neural networks
require 'nn'

-- Set up our neural network
--[[       2             20          20             1
  input[1] -- /--------\ -- /------\ -- /--------\
              | linear | -- | tanh | -- | linear | -- output
  input[2] -- \--------/ -- \------/ -- \--------/
]]--

mlp = nn.Sequential();
inputs = 2; outputs = 1; HUs = 20;
mlp:add(nn.Linear(inputs, HUs));
mlp:add(nn.Tanh());
mlp:add(nn.Linear(HUs, outputs))

-- We want MSE
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()

-- Give 2500 points of training data
print("Iterating...")
for i = 1,2500 do
  local input = torch.randn(2);
  local output = torch.Tensor(1);
  if (input[1] * input[2] > 0) then
    output[1] = -1
  else
    output[1] = 1
  end

  criterion:forward(mlp:forward(input), output)

  mlp:zeroGradParameters()
  mlp:backward(input, criterion:backward(mlp.output, output))
  mlp:updateParameters(0.01)
end
print("Model Trained...")

-- Test model
x = torch.Tensor(2)
x[1] =  0.5; x[2] =  0.5; print(mlp:forward(x));
x[1] =  0.5; x[2] = -0.5; print(mlp:forward(x));
x[1] = -0.5; x[2] =  0.5; print(mlp:forward(x));
x[1] = -0.5; x[2] = -0.5; print(mlp:forward(x));
```

([GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apnorton/deep-learning/master/nn-tutorial.lua) link if people want to download the file)

Comment: did you compile torch separately on both systems? or did you copy over the torch folder from one system to another instead of compiling?

Comment: @smhx I compiled separately on both systems.  On my professor's server it's a local install, rather than a system-wide install.